# Iterating over files in a directory and remove rows from them based on other file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to iterate over 30 files in directory and remove rows from them based on IDs in other file. The files contain two columns - ID and a value, without column names. The other file contains just a column with the IDs ("id") that should be removed("ids_toberemoved"). After the 30 files are cleaned I want to export them to other folder.

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

ids_toberemoved = pd.read_csv('F:\\ids.csv')

myPath = "F:\\Other"

filesList= []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(myPath):
    for name in files:
        filesList.append(os.path.join(name))

dataframes = []

for filename in filesList:
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

for df in dataframes:
    df_cleaned = df.merge(ids_toberemoved, left_index=True, right_on=['id'],
                   how='left', indicator=True)
    df_cleaned[df_cleaned._merge != 'both']
```

I am missing something in the step where I iterate over the data frames and join them with 'ids_toberemoved', in order to delete the rows with the matching IDs. Also, I can't figure out how to store every single file, after the cleaning, to other folder.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach:

```
from pathlib import Path

myPath = Path("F:\\Other")
ids_toberemoved = pd.read_csv('F:\\ids.csv', squeeze=True)

res = pd.concatenate([pd.read_csv(f, header=None, names=["ID","val"])
                        .query("ID not in @ids_toberemoved")
                      for f in myPath.glob("*.csv")], 
                     ignore_index=True)
```

---

**UPDATE:** in order to clean the files and to export them **separately** as `"filename_clean.csv"`:

```
_ = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None, names=["ID","val"])
       .query("ID not in @ids_toberemoved")
       .to_csv(f.with_name(f"{f.stem}_clean{f.suffix}"), index=False)
    for f in myPath.glob("*.csv")]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This approach removes the rows, but concatenates everything in one dataframe. I want to clean the files and to export them separately.